# Sparql join issue

Tags: join, rdf, sparql

I am a bit new to SPARQL and RDF and while I'm loving it, I'm stuck!

So, my app creates a thing with a label 'test6', a unique id and automatically it creates a default chapter associated with 'test6', with an id and a label 'Overview'.  I want all the chapter labels associated with the thing who's label is 'test6' i.e 'Overview'

So the following triples exist (note, I had to trim the predicate because stackoverflow limits links in posts):

```
local:qUak8jXvdkw someOntology:label test6

local:qUak8jXvdkw someOntology:hasChapter qUak8jXvdkwOverview

local:qUak8jXvdkwOverview someOntology:label Overview
```

When I run this query:

```
PREFIX someOntology: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?id, ?chapterId, ?chapterLabel 
WHERE 
{ 
    ?id someOntology:label 'test6' . 
    ?id someOntology:hasChapter ?chapterId . 
    ?chapterId someOntology:label ?chapterLabel .  
}
```

it returns an empty set.

I understand that I can use the Object of a triple as the Subject of another to join them is this correct?

If I use an OPTIONAL{} i.e:

```
PREFIX someOntology: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?id, ?chapterId, ?chapterLabel 
WHERE 
{ 
    ?id someOntology:label 'test6' . 
    ?id someOntology:hasChapter ?chapterId . 
    OPTIONAL{?chapterId someOntology:label ?chapterLabel} .  
}
```

it returns the following:

```
<[{
"id":{"type":"uri","value":"local:qUak8jXvdkw"},
"chapterId":{"type":"literal","value":"qUak8jXvdkwOverview"},
"chapterLabel":{}
}]>
```

I'm using 4store if that's any use.

Thanks in advance for any pointers..

Comment: Partially to the OP, partially to the community: I was aware that SO limits the number of *links* in posts for new users, but if this prevents those new users from asking legitimate questions that happen to contain URL-shaped URIs, this is a serious issue that should be brought up/discussed on Meta.

Comment: Is it intentional that the object in the triple `local:qUak8jXvdkw someOntology:hasChapter qUak8jXvdkwOverview` is not prefixed with a namespace?

Comment: Hi OR Mapper, thanks, I've tried using a namespace, i.e creating a triple with object = 'local:qUak8jXvdkwOverview' but it's giving me the same results, do I need to do something extra in the query, is my notation not correct or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confusion between literals and URIs in the data.

The data has:

```
local:qUak8jXvdkw someOntology:hasChapter qUak8jXvdkwOverview
local:qUak8jXvdkwOverview someOntology:label Overview
```

(did the first line quoted above loose the "" on qUak8jXvdkwOverview - the results suggest it has)

This part

```
?id someOntology:hasChapter ?chapterId .
```

causes result:

```
"chapterId":{"type":"literal","value":"qUak8jXvdkwOverview"},
```

so `?chapterId` here is literal `"qUak8jXvdkwOverview"`.

But the query then has:

```
?chapterId someOntology:label ?chapterLabel .
```

so `?chapterId` here is URI `local:qUak8jXvdkwOverview` (literals can't be subjects anyway).

Comment: Thanks Andy, indeed that was the problem.  I changed my object to a uri using angle brackets instead of quotes in my insert query and I'm unstuck!

Comment: @RobertofRoberston Also note that the projection `select ... where` query isn't legal SPARQL at the moment.  There should not be commas between the variables.  That is, use `SELECT ?id ?chapterId ?chapterLabel`, not `SELECT ?id, ?chapterId, ?chapterLabel `.  You can check with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query).  Also, if AndyS's answer worked for you (and your comment seems to indicate that it did), be sure to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).